Is it possible to use UploadThing with react-native
I'm currently working on a React Native project and I'm looking to use Uploadthing (https://uploadthing.com/) for file uploading. However,after searching extensively, I haven't been able to find any tutorials or guides on how to achieve this.
Has anyone successfully used Uploadthing with React Native before? If so, could someone please provide a guide. Alternatively, if there are any alternative solutions or workarounds for achieving similar functionality in React Native, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

As of now, it doesn't look like they have client components for react native. However, you will be able to use their server lib with node, but you will need to setup custom react native components.
